# Laravel Websocket, and Queue Error (Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed)

Tags: laravel, websocket

Im currently having a problem where I can't queue a job inside a websocket server, my objective is to fire a background job in a specified date and time

I'm having an error that says "An error has occurred: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"

here's is my current code

```
<?php namespace App;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

use App\Http\Controllers\WinIt;

use Cache;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Session;
use Queue;

// Command Classes
use App\Commands\WinItInit;


class WebsocketServer implements MessageComponentInterface {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        // Fire event when current date and time reaches $datetime
        $datetime = '2016-02-10 15:48:08';
        $serialization = Queue::later($datetime, new WinItInit($conn, $this->clients));
    }
}


// The command to fire
<?php namespace App\Commands\WinIt;

use App\Commands\Command;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

// Class Aliases
use DB;
use Input;
use Queue;
use Request;
use Response;
use Session;
use URL;
use Illuminate\Http\Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

// Custom Classes

class WinItInit extends Command implements SelfHandling, ShouldBeQueued {

    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    private $from = null;
    private $clients = null;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($from = null, $clients = null)
    {
        $this->from = $from;
        $this->clients = $clients;
        $this->type = 'sample';
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function handle()
    {
        $data = array();

        switch ($this->type)
        {
            case 'sample':

                $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

                break;
        }

        foreach ($this->clients as $client)
        {
            $client->send(json_encode($data));
        }
    }

}
```